# Toggle div on link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/FsCHJ/2/

what now happens is, whenever I have another link example it will also use this link as the toggle button. I just want Toggle Edit Mode to be toggling hidden div's on/off. So I tried to change `$("a").click(function ()` to `$("toggle").click(function ()` and `<a>Toggle Edit Mode</a>` to Toggle Edit Mode`, but doesn't work. Any idea's?

HTML

```
<li><a>Toggle Edit Mode</a>

</li>
<div class="hidden rightButton">hello</div>
```

CSS

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
.unhidden {
    display: block;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").click(function () {
        $("div").toggleClass("hidden unhidden");
    });
});
```

Comment: $("toggle") is looking for a tag of <toggle>, not a class of .toggle.

Comment: You do not need two classes for show and hide. One does the job.

Comment: You should also post valid markup

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want this.

```
<li><a class="toggle">Toggle Edit Mode</a>

$(".toggle").click(function () {
    $("div").toggleClass("hidden unhidden");
}
```

You cannot use `$("toggle")`, because this looks for the html tag `<toggle>`. Instead add a class `toggle` to the link for which you want to toggle.

Comment: A haha, forgot the . in the JS, I tried that before with class toggle, but didn't work because I used toggle instead of .toggle. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use "ID" selector.

http://jsfiddle.net/FsCHJ/1/

There can be many classes (class=...) in one page but juste on id (id=...) per page. More informations [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp).

---

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#toggle").click(function () {
        $("div").toggleClass("hidden unhidden");
    });
});
```

Html:

```
<li><a id="toggle">Toggle Edit Mode</a></li>

<div class="hidden rightButton">hello</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#toggle").click(function () {
        $("div").toggleClass("hidden unhidden");
    });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
.unhidden {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li><a id="toggle">Toggle Edit Mode</a></li>

<div class="hidden rightButton">hello</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.className` selector:

```
$(".toggle").click(function () {});
```

You can also use jQuery's [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function.

```
$(".toggle").click(function () {
    $("div").toggle();
});
```

Created fiddle to demonstrate [toggle](http://jsfiddle.net/FsCHJ/3/).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Allowing me to show or hide text with the same link. I associate the link with the div i want to show. This works in lists with multiple records, each record having it's own ID.

```
<a class="showHideToggle div1">View Details</a>
<div id="div1" style="display:none;">Record 1 details goes here</div>

<a class="showHideToggle div2">View Details</a>
<div id="div2" style="display:none;">Record 2 details goes here</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".showHideToggle").click(function (ctl) {
            var linkedDivName = $(this).attr('class').replace('showHideToggle ', '');
            var divToToggle = $("#" + linkedDivName);
            //alert('current status: ' + divToToggle.css('display'));

             if (divToToggle.css('display') == 'none') {
                divToToggle.css("display", "block");
                $(this).text("Hide Details");
            } else {
                divToToggle.css("display", "none");
                $(this).text("Show Details");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```